# Oracle VirtualBox webcam problems

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, webcam

Good afternoon, I have a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu on Oracle VirtualBox, but when I try to start application, which uses webcam I have errors/black window. When I try to write this command in terminal in host machine

```
VBoxManage controlvm "Ubuntu Linux" webcam attach
VBoxManage controlvm "Ubuntu Linux" webcam list
```

I have an this error after first command

```
VBoxManage: error: Attach emulated USB webcam (VERR_PDM_NO_USBPROXY)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "WebcamAttach(path.raw(), settings.raw())" at line 1652 of file VBoxManageControlVM.cpp
```

My host OS is Mac OS X.
If someone came across this - please, tell me what to do

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable a USB controller for your VM. In the VirtualBox Manager UIUI by right click on the VM, go to settings -> Ports -> USB, and check "Enable USB Controller" then select "USB 2.0".

Comment: There is only USB1.1

Comment: You need to upgrade your Jabber version @filip.  Newer versions have the USB 2.0 and 3.0 in the USB section of the per-VM settings.